# AppleHighlightColor syntax

Tags: terminal, preferences

I'm changing my highlight color via a command I find in Mathias Bynen's [dotfiles](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx#L44) like so:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleHighlightColor -string "0.764700 0.976500 0.568600"
```

I'd like to change it to something other than green, but I don't understand the syntax that is used for the color configuration (i'm a web developer so anything behind hex or rgba is dark magic to me).

First, what is the color specification?

Second, is there any documentation behind `AppleHighlightColor`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the values for AppleHighlightColor try the following:

1. Pick your desired color
2. Get that color's RGB values
3. Take each value and divide it by 255
4. Put them into the string in order R G B

So, the color:

- Red: 255 => 255/255 = 1
- Green: 152 => 152/255 = 0.5960784314
- Blue: 89 => 89/255 = 0.3490196078

would end up as:

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleHighlightColor -string "1 0.5960784314 0.3490196078"`

Be careful, it's the hightlight color only so you don't want to pick something dark as some (all?) apps don't change the highlighted text color - dark highlight color + black text = hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

The string is RGB with each value ranging from 0.0 to 1.0 (i.e. 1 being 100%, 0 being 0%).

`AppleHighlightColor` is an undocumented setting as far as I can tell.